# EnvInject doesn't read environment variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In Jenkins, I am trying to set up a dynamic environment variable.

I have used [Scriptler](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin?) to create a Groovy script and write the result to a file.

Then, I used [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to read the contents of that file.

The Groovy script:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def GB = build.getEnvVars()["GIT_BRANCH"]
def FORMATED_BRANCH = "com.my.package%3Amy-project%3A" + "${GB}".replace("/", "%2F")

def file = new File('groovyFile')
file.write "FORMATED_BRANCH=${FORMATED_BRANCH}"
```

The setup:

[image]

However, the environment variable that I want to set still isn't recognised:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: quality.gates.jenkins.plugin.QGException: Environment variable with name 'FORMATED_BRANCH' does not exist.
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:236)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
```

Any idea of why the environment variable isn't recognised?

Comment: you can try return the variable, Eg:-   return [FORMATED_BRANCH:${FORMATED_BRANCH}]

Comment: If I return it, then how can I read it from a file? How can I pass it to EnvInject?

Comment: Please provide how you exactly use this environment variable in the Quality Gates plugin.

Comment: you need not to inject it again from file. because once you return it it get added as pre build parameters which can be used in your build and post build steps

Answer (score 0):

You hit this plugin issue [JENKINS-39638](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39638) "Not possible to use environment variable as project key".